# Mocha global hook

Tags: mocha.js, hook

I want to do precompiles my server-side webpack bundles before all tests. So I decide to add file 'helper.js' and put it in mocha.opt to do it.

in helper.js:

```
global.assert = require('assert');

before((done) => {
  startWireMockApi().then(({service, port}) => {
  startFrontenEndService(port)
    .then(frontEndService => {
     done();
  })
  .catch(error => done(error));
  });
});

after(() => {
  console.log("after all........", global.server);
});
```

but I don't know why I still get the error for before all hook: "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

Can anyone help me to look at this? or do we have any other solution to do this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by setting timeout to 30000(more than 2000).